# Alias frequency

Tags: sampling, aliasing

[image]

I have plotted the graph above that has an Amplitude of 1, and a Frequency of 1 Hz. Sampling rate used is 3/4 of a cycle. The book wants me to find out what the alias frequency that the green dots give. I'm confused on what the new alias frequency is?

Any help or guideance would be appreciated.

Edit: This has been solved. Also I put in the wrong values before, but now its fixed and the calculations provided before fixed it. Thank you. 
Answer: 1/4 = 0.25 Hz is the new alias frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Your sampling rate says "the maximum frequency of an oscillation that can be represented is 2/2 Hz = 1 Hz". The assignment wants you to figure out as which frequency below 1 Hz the sampled signal appears.

So, you're on the right track. After how many samples does the sequence of green dots repeat? That gives you the period. And frequency is just 1/period.

By the way: Don't connect values with straight lines, that is strictly-speaking wrong for sampled signals. If you wanted to connect these points with a smooth line, you'd need to do sinc interpolation.

Comment: hmmmm it restarts after 5, but it's only four sample periods long, isn't it?

Comment: don't think in dots, think in sample periods. Yes, it's 1/4 of the sampling rate, because the time of a period is \$T_\text{signal}=4\cdot T_\text{sample} = 4\cdot \frac1{f_\text{sample}}\$, and with \$f_\text{signal}=\frac1{T_\text{signal}}= \frac{f_\text{sample}}4\$.

Comment: You're correct. Thank you! When not looking at the dots it's more clear.